# Mysql can' t install on ubuntu 18.04 " Specified filename /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 does not exist."

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I new i 've since few days a mysql error when i install myql-server on ubuntu 18.04 i read many solution but the probleme is not solve yet please anynone can help me thank

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Specified filename /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 does not exist.
Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Warning: Unable to start the server. Please restart MySQL and run mysql_upgrade to ensure the database is ready for use.
Specified filename /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 does not exist.
Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-22 12:21:24 CEST; 8ms ago
  Process: 13030 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```